# What can cause legit MySql INSERT INTO command to fail?

Tags: sql, mysql, reserved-words

I can't figure out what's causing my INSERT INTO's to fail to  certain table in MySql. I can manage them to other tables. The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Match` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `season` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hometeam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `awayteam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `match_no` (`match_no`),
  KEY `season` (`season`),
  KEY `hometeam` (`hometeam`),
  KEY `awayteam` (`awayteam`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And the command is

```
INSERT INTO Match (`match_no`, `season`, `hometeam`, `awaytem`) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 3)
```

All I get is:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Match (`match_no`, `season`, `hometeam`, `awaytem`) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 3)' at line 1

I have checked the manual and half-a-dozen examples from the web and whatnought and tried all sorts of changes to the syntax in case there is some MySql specific oddity, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `awaytem` to `awayteam` and see how it goes and use `Match` as the table: `match` is a reserved word.

Comment: Ah, the awaytem was just a typo I did when I quickly wrote the example, but the other hint was the key! So thank's a lot, can't believe how much time I wasted on this...

Comment: As a side note: While you *can* use a reserved word as a table/column name in MySQL (and other DMBS), I'd strongly recommend against it. It will be a source of trouble in the future, and not all tools may support the necessary tricks (such as using quotes). Just use a different table name, if you can.

Comment: Yeah, I don't usually use them, but this is just a small app that once I get ready will probably never touch again.

Answer (score 4):

`Match` is a `reserved` word in `MySQL`.

Here goes the [list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) of MySQL reserved words

Enclose Match in back ticks as:

```
INSERT INTO `Match` .........
```

Also as Pax pointed out you've misspelt a column name.

Comment: Think you mean "reserved" word :)

Answer (score 2):

Match is a reversed word
so,

```
INSERT INTO `Match`
```

note the same backticks you used for the fieldnames
these are not for decoration